# Numerical algebra using a Matrix class

Tags: c++, matrix

I would like to make a `Matrix` class. Can any of you help me about this class?

There are two ways:

```
#include <iostream>

class Matrix {

private:
    double** array;
    int row, column;

public:

    Matrix(int m, int n) {
        this->row=m;
        this->column=n;
        this->array = new double*[m];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            this->array[i] = new double[n];
            std::fill(array[i],array[i]+n,0.0);
        }
    }

    Matrix(Matrix &matrix){
        this->array=matrix.array;
        this->row=matrix.row;
        this->column=matrix.column;

    }
    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& rhs ){
        this->row=rhs.row;
        this->column=rhs.column;
        for(int i=0;i<row;++i)
            for(int j=0;j<column;++j)
                this->array[i][j]=rhs.array[i][j];
    }

    ~Matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this->row; i++)
            delete[] this->array[i];
        delete[] this->array;
    }

   void print(){
        for(int i=0;i<this->row;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<this->column;++j)
                printf("%f\t",this->array[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }

    }
    double * operator [](int m){
        return this->array[m];
    }
};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Matrix A(2,2);
    A[0][1]=1;
    A[0][0]=0;
    A[1][0]=1;
    A[1][1]=1;
    A.print();
    return 0;
  }
```

The other one using `vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Matrix {

private:
vector< vector<double> > array;
int row, column;

public:

Matrix(int m, int n) {
    row = m;
    column = n;
    array = vector< vector<double> > (m, vector<double> (n, 0));
}


Matrix(Matrix &matrix){
    this->array=matrix.array;
    this->row=matrix.row;
    this->column=matrix.column;

}
void print(){
    for(int i=0;i<this->row;++i){
        for(int j=0;j<this->column;++j)
            printf("%f\t",this->array[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

 }
 vector<double> & operator [](int m){
     return this->array[m];
 }
 };
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking is what we say when you don't describe what the code does.  What kind of numerical algebra are you doing with your matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `vector<vector<int>>` instead of `p`, `m`, and `n`.

No need to manage memory (using `new` and `delete`) - the `vector` class will take care of that.

BTW, your `operator=` is pretty nasty.

Instead of replicating the allocated data pointed by `p`, it copies the value of `p`.

As a result, you will get two `matrix` objects sharing the same data.

If you change one, then you essentially change the other.

If you deallocate one (dynamically or statically at the end of the scope in which it is allocated), then the other one will hold a pointer to an unallocated memory block.

Comment: it is problem with the function operator=? how to implement it ?

Comment: @YaoJiahao: More or less the same way in which you've implemented the constructor. But again - I think that you'd be much better off with `vector<vector>> int` instead of what you currently have.

Comment: Can you see that I have changed my way ? I add my change in my question? This time , am I okey ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @YaoJiahao: Your question now looks like a chat. This is not the way to post questions here. Please fix it to be aligned with the conventions on this website - post only the relevant piece o code. Ask **concrete questions** (i.e., not "is it okay?") about whatever you have doubts with, so that me and others on this website will be able to refer to it.

Comment: I know! I will change it soon!

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
 using namespace std;
```

This is a matter of taste, when used in implementation, but I personally prefer fully-qualified names (given that `std` is only three characters)

2)

```
class matrix
{
   int **p, m, n;
```

I'd argue that `m` and `n` would be known to people who read math books, but there's no excuse for not renaming `p` to something more telling.

3)

```
 p[i] = new int[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        p[i][j] = 0;
```

You can use `memset` or `std::fill` instead of loop here

4)

```
matrix& operator+ (const matrix& m1)
{
    return (*this += m1);
}

matrix& operator* (const matrix& m1)
{
    return (*this *= m1);
}
```

Semantics are kind of clunky here. A user does not not expect `operator*` and `operator+` to mutate an existing matrix. You should return a different object here.

5)

```
matrix& operator= (const matrix& T)
  {
    p = T.p;
    n = T.n;
    m = T.m;

    return *this;
}
```

I'd also check for self-assignment here:

```
if(*this != matrix)
```

Comment: `This is a matter of taste` [No, it's highly regarded as a lousy practice.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) It will bite you in the behind later. Don't be coy, you can say OP should drop the practice.

Comment: @Mast I agree, but sometimes it's useful when you restrict it to say a function scope. Also, while not entirely related to my point, I assume OP used ideone, that inserts it by default.

Comment: It's a bad habit promoted by many, not just ideone. Heck, even my first C++ book promotes it.